# SSRS Multivalued parameter to pass 'ALL'

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report which has 10 parameters and user wants to see 'ALL' values from the parameters as a default. Each of the parameter has a list of 100 values in them, passing all of them as a default value is impacting the performance. How to add a single 'All' value that the report interprets as meaning all the options ? I am a beginner in SSRS , so please pardon me. I have tried a couple of options but couldn't make the report working.

The report is driven by a sp and has corresponding datasets to drive the parameters. The sp has 2 ctes which pull data from different sources and lastly it has a union between the 2 ctes to show all data available from both sources.

In the where clause , I am using a splitfunction which will split when I pass multiple sources. I am explicitly mentioning 'ALL' for the parameters. 
Here is a sample of what I have done so far

```
    Create procedure dbo.Testreport
    @BusinessUnit varhar(max),
    @State varchar(max),
    @Class varchar(max),
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date,
    @Source varchar(10)
    AS begin
    ;with ABC
    As
     ( Select CustomerName, CustID, Address, 
      StateName,Business,ClassCode,EffectiveDate,ExpirationDate,Source='FDM'
       From table A),

    XYZ AS
        ( Select CustomerName, CustID, Address, 
      StateName,Business,ClassCode,EffectiveDate,ExpirationDate,Source='MAS'
       From table B),
      ReportingData As
      ( Select * from ABC
       UNION
       Select * from XYZ) select * from ReportingData 
       where Source in(select * from dbo.fnsplit(@Source))
       and @BusinessUnit = 'ALL' or Business=@BusinessUnit
       and @State ='ALL' or State=@State
       and @Class='ALL'or ClassCode=@Class
       and EffectiveDate>=@StartDate and ExpirationDate<=@EndDate
       END
```

In the 2012 Report Builder , for the parameters dataset, I am doing something like
Dataset BusinessUnit

```
    ;with BU
     As (Select BUID,BusinessUnit from table A
           union
       Select BUID, BusinessUnit from table B)
       select '-1' as BUID, 'ALL' as BusinessUnit
        UNION
       select '1' as BUID, BusinessUnit From BU
```

Then in the @BuisnessUnit parameter , I am using'ALL' to set the Default value Tab.
When I run the report in report builder , in the preview pane I dont see any data. What is possibly wrong with the design?

Any pointer would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using table valued parameters? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Answer (score 0):

There could be other problems in the parts of the code you haven't shown us, but one thing you need to fix is using parenthesis in your where clause.

Instead of this:

```
   where Source in(select * from dbo.fnsplit(@Source))
   and @BusinessUnit = 'ALL' or Business=@BusinessUnit
   and @State ='ALL' or State=@State
   and @Class='ALL'or ClassCode=@Class
   and EffectiveDate>=@StartDate and ExpirationDate<=@EndDate
```

You need this:

```
   where Source in(select * from dbo.fnsplit(@Source))
   and (@BusinessUnit = 'ALL' or Business=@BusinessUnit)
   and (@State ='ALL' or State=@State)
   and (@Class='ALL'or ClassCode=@Class)
   and EffectiveDate>=@StartDate 
   and ExpirationDate<=@EndDate
```